# Sonar includes test files in the Components view. Is this right?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using Sonar on Java and Ant. I use static code analysis and import test results from our CI server.

When looking at the "Components" view in Sonar, that view contains both source code and test code. Rules and test coverage are displayed correctly for source code, but nothing is displayed for tests. I am wondering if having test files in this view affects the overall statistics on code Coverage. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the components view should not include the test files by default. Check our demo Sonar instance, for instance:

- classes of the Sonar Code Colorizer module: http://nemo.sonarsource.org/components/index/182946 (no test classes are displayed)
- test classes of this module can be found here: http://nemo.sonarsource.org/drilldown/measures/182945?metric=tests

This probably means that you mixed test and source classes together, or that the Sonar configuration in your Ant script is not correct.

Comment: I see. Are you able to point out what part of the Ant imports resources to the Components view? Ant is importing sources from sources, tests from tests, and binaries from source binaries (not test).

Comment: Well, that would help if you could add - in your question description - the part of the Ant script that defines the Sonar properties. You can also have a look at our Ant project examples to find where the problem can be: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/ant and https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/ut/ant